# Try method in powershell

Tags: powershell, wmi

So I want to build a try method into my powershell script below. If I am denied access to a server, I want it to skip that server. Please help..

```
[code]$Computers = "server1", "server2"

Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalMemoryConfiguration -Computer $Computers | Select-Object `
@{n='Server';e={ $_.__SERVER }}, `
@{n='Physical Memory';e={ "$('{0:N2}' -f ($_.TotalPhysicalMemory / 1024))mb" }}, `
@{n='Virtual Memory';e={ "$('{0:N2}' -f ($_.TotalPageFileSpace / 1024))mb" }} | `
Export-CSV "output.csv"[/code]
```

Answer (score 4):

Try/catch functionality is built-into PowerShell 2.0 e.g.:

```
PS> try {$i = 0; 1/$i } catch { Write-Debug $_.Exception.Message }; 'moving on'
Attempted to divide by zero.
moving on
```

Just wrap you script in a similar try/catch.  Note you could totally ignore the error by leaving the catch block empty `catch { }` but I would recommend at least spitting out the error info if your $DebugPreference is set to 'Continue'.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply suppress errors with the ErrorAction parameter:

Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalMemoryConfiguration -Computer $Computers -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | ...

Comment: Just to qualify that statement a bit - you can suppress "non-terminating" errors with the ErrorAction parameter. :-)

Comment: Indeed, thanks Keith :) (Wmi's 'Access Denied' is a "non-terminating" error)

Answer (score 0):

You can use trap to replicate Try/Catch, see http://huddledmasses.org/trap-exception-in-powershell/ or http://weblogs.asp.net/adweigert/archive/2007/10/10/powershell-try-catch-finally-comes-to-life.aspx for examples.

Comment: In V2, there is built in support for try/catch/finally. The posts are out of date.

Answer (score 0):

Use a filter function? [Like this tutorial explains.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2007.08.powershell.aspx)

He passes a list of computers to his pipeline - first it tries to ping each one, and then only passes the ones that respond to the next command (reboot). You could customize this for whatever actual functionality you wanted.